# Why does cel-shading sometimes look similar to rotoscoping?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing

Why does cel-shading sometimes look similar to rotoscoping?

Rotoscoping: A Scanner Darkly:

[image: http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/Waking_Life_rotoscoping_372.jpg]

Cel-shading: Wikipedia: Cel-shading, Teapot Example:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Celshading_teapot_large.png/700px-Celshading_teapot_large.png]

Comment: Or is this the wrong stackexchange for this question? I put this question here, because I thought Cel-shading and Rotoscoping are types of image processing... If you think I'm wrong, please vote to move...

Comment: Graphics does seem like an odd mix between DSP and gamedev that doesn't quite fit in either :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out the Wikipedia page for rotoscoping and it says one way it was done is that a live action image was shown behind frosted glass and an animator would draw it.  The frosted glass detail obfuscation coupled with the fact that it was a cartoonist means to me that you are going to get solid colored areas as shading, like you'd see in a cartoon.  Cell shading is basically trying to make the same effect but using 3d rendered graphics as a source instead of an actual photographed image.  Seems like they are the same effect, just with different names!